# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')

Tags: node.js

I am new to node js. I need help.

There is a list of users on the account page and I want to update the balance value of a user in this list on the deposit page. When I send value from deposit url below, I get the error in the header. I tried post and put. I want to send value rather than update value

**account.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();


let accounts = [];
exports.accounts = accounts;
let balance = 0;
exports.balance = balance;

// Create Account

router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {


    let accountNumber = req.body.accountNumber
    let currencyCode = req.body.currencyCode.toUpperCase()
    let ownerName = req.body.ownerName
    let accountType = req.body.accountType.toLowerCase()

    let isExist = accounts.find(item => item.accountNumber == accountNumber)


    if (currencyCode != "TRY" && currencyCode != "USD" && currencyCode != "EUR") {
        res.send("Undefined currency code")

    } else if (accountType != "individual" && accountType != "corporate") {
        res.send("Undefined account type")

    } else if (accountNumber.constructor != Number) {
        res.send("Account number must be a numeric value")

    } else if (isExist) {
        res.send("Already have an account")


    } else {
        accounts.push({
            accountNumber: accountNumber,
            currencyCode: currencyCode,
            ownerName: ownerName,
            accountType: accountType,
            balance
        })
        res.status(200).json({
            message: "Succesfuly"
        })
    }

});

// Get Account Info

router.get('/:accountNumber', (req, res, next) => {

    let accountNumber = req.params.accountNumber
    let isExist = accounts.find(item => item.accountNumber == accountNumber)
    let accountInfo = isExist


    if (isExist) {
        res.status(200).json({
            accountInfo,

        })
    } else {
        res.status(404).json({
            message: "Not found"
        })
    }


});

module.exports = router;
```

**deposit.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const { is } = require('express/lib/request');
const { accounts, balance } = require('./account');
const router = express.Router();

// Deposit 

    router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    
        let accountNumber = req.body.accountNumber
        let amount = req.body.amount
    
        isExist = accounts.find(item => item.accountNumber == accountNumber)
    
        accounts[isExist].balance += amount
    
        return accounts[isExist]
    
    
    })
    
    
    
    module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

You mixing both `exports` and `module.exports` and at the end of `account.js` you have the following line `module.exports = router;` This basically overwrites everything that you exported before.

In your case you probably want to do remove all the non `module.exports` and instead do something like:

```
module.exports = {router, accounts, balance};
```

Then require it accordingly, e.g.:

```
const { accounts, balance } = require('./account');
```

Or if you want to access the router, e.g.:

```
const {router: accountRouter} = require('./account');
app.use('/account', accountRouter);
```

Comment: when ı add this module.exports = {router, accounts, balance};
give app is crashed error

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: https://ctxt.io/2/AADgXL2IEA

Comment: errors detail is in paste link

Comment: And how do you `require` it in your `application.js` ?